# What is the meaning of "auch schon"?

Tags: meaning

In my textbook I found the phrase *"Meine Augen tun auch schon ein bisschen weh"*. I want to know the meaning of *"auch schon"* in general and when to use it

Comment: "auch schon" means "aswell". The "auch" part literally means "too"  and the "schon" part means literally "already". Could be used when someone told you their eyes hurt because of some external stimuli (e.g. teargas). And you reply "my eyes have started to hurt aswell". Or when someone remarks something and you think it's obvious, you can reply (sarcastically) "Hast du das auch schon gemerkt?".

Comment: The "auch" does not necessarily mean "too" or "as well". It can also suggest causality. Assume there's tear gas. "Meine Augen tun schon ein bisschen weh." means "They are hurting already.". "Meine Augen tun *auch* schon ein bisschen weh." means "They are hurting already *because of the tear gas*."

Comment: @usr hmm, I think I have seen that being used. But it highly depends on the accentuation and context. "Meine Augen tun *auch* schon ein bisschen weh" doesn't suggest causality. But "Meine Augen tuen auch schon ein bisschen *weh*." might suggest causality.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I would say it depends on the context what it means. I had no idea that German is such a crazily complicated language.

Answer (score 2):

- auch = also, too
- schon = already

Other parts of speech:

- meine Augen = my eyes
- tun ... weh = hurt
- ein bisschen = a little bit

All together:

> My eyes **also already** hurt a little bit.

Comment: "Auch" doesn't necessarily mean "also", "too". This would require that there's someone else whose eyes hurt. But consider the following context: "Ich sitze seit 10 Stunden am Computer. Meine Augen tun auch schon ein bisschen weh." There is no other person, so the meaning cannot be "also", "too.". It's just a particle that could be dropped altogether.

Comment: @Em1: There is no need for another person, neither in German nor in English: »I am sitting on the computer for 10 hours, and my eyes also already hurt a little bit.« With this sentence you tell, that you suffer from two things: a) sitting 10 hours on the computer, and b) also eyes that hurt.

Comment: I think in German, it's more subtle than that. I have heard "auch" being used as a fill word like @Em1 describes.

Comment: In some cases "auch" can be translated better as "what's more". A problem with "auch" and similar words is that they are used a lot more in German than in English. But usually they are not mere filler words but add some nuance.